# REPO (aosp) switch between branches

Tags: android, repo

I have some issues in understanding how **repo** works, specifically  how to switch between branches.

I did

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`

and then

`repo sync`.

Based on my understanding my repo branch should be on master, but when I run

`repo branch`

the output is `no branches`.

I want to know how can I switch between branches. Should I run

`repo init` and `repo sync`

every time I want to switch branch (`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1`) or is there any similarity with git flow (`git checkout <branch>`). How can I create new local branch for developing?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

repo doesn't use branches the same way git does. With repo, you are not on a branch until you start a unit of work with the "repo start" command.  repo start puts you on a dev branch based on the head of the branch you specified with the -b option in your repo init command.  Once you're done with a local dev branch and you either repo prune it or repo abandon it, you go back to a no branch state (or it can also say you are detached, it means the same thing).

Comment: So, if I am on the head of `-b android-4.4.4_r2` and then I run `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.0.0_r1.0.1 && repo sync` in the same working directory, this will then just download additional manifest file and files for android version 5 or all `sync` process will begin from the start and overwrite my working directory?

Comment: Everything will happen in your current working directory.  repo will attempt to warn you if any of your work will be lost and may prompt you to use the --force-sync option.  To be completely safe, I would suggest making sure your working directory is clean (no dev branches, no modified files). Use repo status to check before doing a repo init.